# Let equation $\sum_{k=0}^n\begin{pmatrix} n\\k\end{pmatrix} ^2x^{n-k}=0$. Proved that...

Tags: sequences-and-series

Problem:

Proved that with all n is positive integer, let equation:

$$\begin{pmatrix} n\\0\end{pmatrix} ^2x^n+\begin{pmatrix} n\\1\end{pmatrix} ^2x^{n-1}+\cdots+\begin{pmatrix} n\\n\end{pmatrix} ^2=0$$

Have n real-root diacritical and which are all negative real root!

P.s

I don not kow how! Please help!

Comment: The coefficients are all positive?

Comment: Your constant term is 1 and the product of the roots must thus be 1.  If they are all negative that won't work for n odd.  Also I don't know what you mean by "diacritical".

Comment: @BettyMock You got it wrong, a negative root $-a$ yields a factor $x+a$, in the product everything will be positive and allright.

Comment: @Ewan, so true.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the result shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338722/how-prove-that-polynomial-has-only-real-root/340526#340526).

I don’t know if there is a simpler proof.