# Prove that if all of the roots of a polynomial $P(z)$ are real, then for any $b$ the roots of the polynomial $R(z)=P(z+ib)+P(z-ib)$ are also real.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

> Prove that if all of the roots of a polynomial $P(z)$ are real, then for any $b$ the roots of the polynomial $R(z)=P(z+ib)+P(z-ib)$ are also real.

I'm just trying take the polynomial $$P(z)=a_0+a_1z+\dotsb+a_nz^n$$ and look at $$P(z+bi)=a_0+a_1(z+bi)+\dotsb+a_n(z+bi)^n$$ and $$P(z-bi)=a_0+a_1(z-bi)+\dotsb+a_n(z-bi)^n$$ and then considering $$P(z+ib)+P(z-ib)=2a_0+2a_1z+2a_2(z^2-b^2)+\dotsb$$  we can see that every term hasn't the imaginary part, i.e all of $i$ are missing and we get new polynomial $G$ which have coefficients as in a polynomial $P(z)$ multiplying on $b$. But how to explain that all of the roots of $R(z)$ are real?

Comment: I take it that the coefficients of $P$ are assumed to be real, not complex ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy The condition does not say, it is said only about the roots

Comment: We can assume that the coefficients are real, otherwise we just divide by the leading coefficient and they become real. Assume also $b>0$. If $P$ has all $n$ roots real, where $n$ is its degree, then $P(z-ib)$ has all roots in the upper half plane. Therefore the image of the real axis by $P(z-ib)$ winds around the origin $n$ times. In particular, it intersects the imaginary axis $n$ times. But each time $P(z-ib)$ is imaginary, its conjugate is $P(z+ib)$. Therefore, all those $n$ times, $P(z+ib)+P(z-ib)$ vanishes.

Comment: @orole: Couldn't multiple intersection points on the imaginary axis coincide? It probably remains to show that this gives *all* roots of $P(z+ib)+P(z-ib)$.

Comment: @MartinR You mean like $P(r-ib)=P(s-ib)=iA$ for reals $r\neq s$, $A$? Yes, that gives you two different roots for $P(z-ib)+P(z+ib)$. Touching the imaginary axis with high order is just the same. If $P(z-ib)-iA$ is divisible by $(z-r)^m$, with $r$ real, then $P(z-ib)+P(z+ib)$ is divisible by $(z-r)^m$. The counting in the winding number counts multiplicities.

Comment: @orole do you have a reference for your results on winding numbers ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy It is called the [Argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle). You can find it in almost all complex analysis courses.

Comment: @orole I know about the argument principle. My question was, how do you deduce your claim that the image of the real axis winds around the origin $n$ times ? Which closed curve do you apply the argument principle to ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy You said you know about the argument principle. That's the argument principle. The real axis, traveled from left to right, encloses all roots of $P(z-ib)$, which lie all in the upper half plane. Therefore, its image by $P(z-ib)$ winds $n$ times. Yes, closed curve in the Riemann sphere.

Comment: The "Riemann sphere" part is the thing that confuses me. The link you gave only mentions the argument principle for curves of the form $[a,b] \to {\mathbb C}$, where $[a,b]$ is a compact interval. So what I'm asking you is a reference that explains the extension of the argument principle to the Riemann sphere. The Riemann sphere is not "part of almost all complex analysis courses" ...

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Take a large half-disk in the upper half-plane, say with centre $0$ and radius $R$. If $R$ is large enough, it will contain all zeros of the polynomial, so $P(z-ib)$ winds around the origin $n$ times on the boundary of the half-disk. Total change of argument is $2\pi n$. And if $R$ is large enough, the behaviour of $P(z-ib)$ is dominated by the leading term on the semicircle, so the change of argument on the semicircle is $\pi n + O(1/R)$. Hence the change of argument on $[-R,R]$ is also $\pi n + O(1/R)$. Letting $R\to \infty$, we see that the change of argument on $\mathbb{R}$ is

Comment: $\pi n$, so the image of the real axis winds around $0$ exactly $\frac{n}{2}$ times. Since - assuming real coefficients, as we may - the argument starts at some $k\pi$ at $-\infty$ it ends up at $(k+n)\pi$ and the image crosses the imaginary axis (when the argument is $\bigl(m+\frac{1}{2}\bigr)\pi$) at least $n$ times. Since each crossing of the imaginary axis yields a zero of $R$, the image has exactly $n$ points on the imaginary axis, otherwise $R$ would have too many zeros.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for taking the time to write all those explanations down. I believe though that they have their place as comments here as I'm not the only one who will get confused reading orole's quick sketch

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial solution, based on an idea by Martin R. 
First of all, by rescaling we may assume without loss that $b=1$ ; we then have to deal with $Q=P(X-i)+P(X+i)$.

Martin's idea was to use a result by Saddeev & Sominski, that if $\sum_{k=0}^m\gamma_k X^k$  has only real roots then the same is true of $\sum_{k=0}^m\gamma_k P^{(k)}$ (see the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338722/how-prove-that-polynomial-has-only-real-root?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

So we try to write $Q$ as a linear combination of derivatives of $P$. It turns out that

$$
Q=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} P^{(2k)} \tag{1}
$$

(the formula is easy to show by checking that it works for every monomial). So Martin's idea works iff the polynomial $C_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \frac{(-x^2)^k}{(2k)!} $ has only real roots. This holds  for $n\leq 5$, but unfortunately becomes false for $n=6$. Note that $C_n$ is the Taylor expansion of the cosine function.

So this method only shows the result when the degree of $P$ is $\leq 5$.