# $\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ splits $\Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^n \frac {a_k} {k!}x^k$ splits over reals

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials

Suppose that $a_0, a_1, \ldots a_n \in \mathbb R$ and the polynomial $P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ has all real roots. I'm supposed to show that
$$
Q(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac {a_k} {k!}x^k
$$
also has this property, i.e. it has all $n$ (possibly non-distinct) real roots.

I know that I'm supposed to show my progress, but I can't find any useful path. Perhaps a proof by induction on $n$ would be helpful - differentiating $Q$ leaves a similar polynomial to work with. I wasn't able to progress though. I would appreciate some clue (not full solution!).

Comment: Did you see this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338722/how-prove-that-polynomial-has-only-real-root/340526#340526

Comment: @Nastar no, but it apparently solves my problem. How to mark it?

Comment: No idea. Nice question, though. Is your source for this question same as the source given in that answer?

Comment: @Nastar no, its my homework set from real analysis class (second semester).

Comment: I've seen this question before, it was in one of the problem sets Don Zagier gave after his lectures: http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/ems/Zagier/Problems.html